# Parsing image data from json

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm writing an Android app that shows images and a short description about the images, currently using a YouTube tutorial to get things going.

For some reason I can't parse the `JSON` correctly, and I am unable to show the images and info.

any help would be appreciated, here is my `JSON` formats:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fernandopuma/d33dffc07c9dfec267ff2029e79ad125/raw/fff8018e890d34b690bfaeda630249917dd2bc42/galeria.json

And this:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/draskomikic/372a8ca88d6d88ec2e45/raw/e95badd14bf24abc1b7a6dfdf4a8070515650eca

The second one is currently sitting in my project inside  `values/strings.xml` :

```
<string name="gallery_feed">https://gist.githubusercontent.com/draskomikic/372a8ca88d6d88ec2e45/raw/e95badd14bf24abc1b7a6dfdf4a8070515650eca</string>
```

This works with `JSON` example:

```
.../com.tutsplus.zoo E/Zoo: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PaulTR/GettingStartedWithAndroid/master/images/gallery/thumbnail_grizzly.jpg
```

But this what I get with the json I made

```
.../com.tutsplus.zoo E/Zoo: Retrofit error 404 Not Found
```

And this is the code to get the JSON

```
public class GalleryImage {

private String thumbnail;
private String image;
private String caption;

public GalleryImage() {

}

public GalleryImage(String thumbnail, String image, String caption) {
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    this.image = image;
    this.caption = caption;
}

public String getThumbnail() {
    return thumbnail;
}

public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getCaption() {
    return caption;
}

public void setCaption(String caption) {
    this.caption = caption;
}
}
```

The interface class:

```
public interface GalleryApiInterface {

@GET("/Gallery")
void getStreams(Callback<List<GalleryImage>> callback);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The link returns 404, fix it first.

Comment: and how to I fix that? I uploaded in gist.github.com, any suggestions? well that was an older but I enter this one and still nothing
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fernandopuma/e96b9225d8386c293a2eb029a0c4ec4d/raw/eba2646e82af618c32edc6d41be01d78a42080cd/gallery.json

Comment: what's the url you're passing to Retrofit when initializing it?

Comment: also, remove the "/" from the GET annotation, make it `@GET("Gallery")`. i have a feeling Retrofit assumes "/Gallery" as a root.

Comment: nop it returns this
05-15 12:46:23.685 26380-26380/com.tutsplus.zoo E/Zoo: Retrofit error GalleryApiInterface.getStreams: URL path "Gallery" must start with '/'.

Comment: sorry, can't help you more. the only thing I get is that you aren't receiving your data, and with this code only I can't find the problem.

Comment: well this is my project I uploaded to Github, hope you help cuz I'm getting nuts https://github.com/fernandopuma/ferchocolate.git

Comment: When providing additional info based on questions, it's better to edit it into the original question than provide it in comments.  Future potential answers can get all of the available info in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson to map JSON directly to your model and it's pretty simple to use..

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
GalleryImage galleryImage = gson.fromJson(yourJsonObject, GalleryImage.class);
```

Comment: should I implementing this on the interface class ??

Comment: No, make your model implement Serializable and then import this library..